# Cropping polygon with OpenCV rotates the polygon

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to cut a parking spot from a large (1920x1080) image using OpenCV in Python like this:

```
def cut_polygon_ROI_from_img(image: np.ndarray, ROI) -> np.ndarray:
    x, y, w, h = ROI.bounding_rect
    cropped = image[x:x + w, y:y + h].copy()

    points_arr = ROI.points - ROI.points.min(axis=0)
    mask = np.zeros(cropped.shape[:2], np.uint8)
    cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, points_arr, color=(255, 255, 255))

    cropped = cv2.bitwise_and(cropped, cropped, mask=mask)
    return cropped
```

I measured the bounding points (which are in `ROI.points`) by hand. The `ROI.bounding_rect` holds the `cv2.boundingRect(points)` tuple, which was created from the points that I've measured by hand:

```
[[ 275 1420]
 [ 279 1531]
 [ 454 1616]
 [ 453 1503]]
```

Points are organized from top left clockwise. For some reason, after cutting I get:

[image]

For checking, I've cut a rectangle from `[ 275 1420]` (top left) to `[ 454 1616]` (bottom right) and I have:

[image]

As you can see, first and third points are OK, but second and fourth are flipped, i. e. reflected along the diagonal from first to third point. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, not only the second and last points are flipped, but all the 4 points are flipped. The first and third points have x and y coordinate almost the same that is why it is looking correct.

I am not sure where this problem is arising from but I think it is arising from this line:

```
points_arr = ROI.points - ROI.points.min(axis=0)
```

It is seen that numpy sometimes returns the coordinates in [y, x] format instead of [x, y] format.

Thus, to solve this problem, you can flip the `points_arr` variable before cv2.fillConvexPoly() function and this will solve the problem. You can do this by using the following line:

```py
points_arr = np.fliplr(points_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the problem, which has to do with OpenCV weird coordinate requirements:

- for functions operating on single points (or lists of single points) **it requires the order of coordinates: (column, row)**
- for functions operating on lists of points for drawing (e. g. drawing polygons) **it requires the points to be sorted counterclockwise, starting with the point with the lowest row (2nd coordinate, Y)**

I had to sort the points counterclockwise, and then flip coordinates:

```
def cut_polygon_ROI_from_img(image: np.ndarray, ROI) -> np.ndarray:
    x, y, w, h = ROI.bounding_rect
    cropped = image[x:x + w, y:y + h].copy()

    points_arr = ROI.points - ROI.points.min(axis=0)
    # OpenCV requires coordinates [column, row] for single points
    points_arr[:, [0, 1]] = points_arr[:, [1, 0]]

    mask = np.zeros(cropped.shape[:2], np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(image=mask,
                     contours=[points_arr],
                     contourIdx=-1,
                     color=(255, 255, 255),
                     thickness=-1,  # fill the area bounded by contours
                     lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

    cropped = cv2.bitwise_and(cropped, cropped, mask=mask)
    return cropped
```